# What is a Finale Number™?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Finale Number™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Finale Numbers™ | Not Finale Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 28 | 30 |
| 55 | 53 |
| 388 | 776 |
| 514 | 207 |
| 982 | 984 |
| 1765 | 1763 |
| 4978 | 9956 |
| 6040 | 3020 |
| 8110 | 8112 |
| 19999 | 19997 |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Finale Numbers™,Not Finale Numbers™
28,30
55,53
388,776
514,207
982,984
1765,1763
4978,9956
6040,3020
8110,8112
19999,19997
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Finale Number™ is a number such that,

> When you add its digits, add the digits of that result, and add the digits of *that* result and so on, you finish with $1$. This is called the digital root of a number. (Finale numbers™ have digital root $1$)

Finale Numbers™:

> $19999\rightarrow 1+9+9+9+9=37$
>  $37\rightarrow 3+7=10$
>  $10\rightarrow 1+0=1$
>  
>  $8110\rightarrow 8+1+1+0=10$
>  $10\rightarrow 1+0=1$
>  
>  $4978\rightarrow 4+9+7+8=28$
>  $28\rightarrow 2+8=10$
>  $10\rightarrow 1+0=1$

Not Finale Numbers™:

> $19997\rightarrow 1+9+9+9+7=35$
>  $35\rightarrow 3+5=8$
>  
>  $3020\rightarrow 3+0+2+0=5$
>  
>  $8112\rightarrow 8+1+1+2=12$
>  $12\rightarrow 1+2=3$

This is equivalent to: (thanks @athin!)

> A Finale Number™ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $9$.

Comment: Actually, it is equivalent to: "jura gur ahzore vf qvivqrq ol avar, gur erzvaqre jvyy or bar". :)

Comment: Looks so! rot13(Vs lbh trg a ol qbvat guvf gur ahzore zhfg or a zbq avar evtug?)

Comment: yep, exactly ^^

Comment: You might want to include the mathematical terms: rot13(qvtvgny ebbg & zbqhyb 9), which aren't equivalent methods but do give equivalent results for this puzzle.

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice that there has a math property here:P, Good job!

Answer (score 3):

To be precise, my answer is also in the same lines as that of

> supersonic, but with a generalization at sum of the digits of the given number level. It is of the form ( (9*n) +1)- for Finale numbers and we cannot do so for their counterparts